# Parsing content using grep, awk

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have a parsed content similar to this as a output from JSON.sh.

```
["/home/ukrishnan/projects/test.yml","LOG_DRIVER"]  "syslog"
["/home/ukrishnan/projects/test.yml","IMAGE"]   "mysql:5.6"
["/home/ukrishnan/projects/test.yml"]   {"LOG_DRIVER":"syslog","IMAGE":"mysql:5.6"}
["/home/ukrishnan/projects/mysql/app.xml","ENV_ACCOUNT_BRIDGE_ENDPOINT"]    "/u01/src/test/sample.txt"
["/home/ukrishnan/projects/mysql/app.xml"]  {"ENV_ACCOUNT_BRIDGE_ENDPOINT":"/u01/src/test/sample.txt"}
[]  {"/home/ukrishnan/projects/test.yml":{"LOG_DRIVER":"syslog","IMAGE":"mysql:5.6"},"/home/ukrishnan/projects/mysql/app.xml":{"ENV_ACCOUNT_BRIDGE_ENDPOINT":"/u01/src/test/sample.txt"}}
```

So, I just wanted to take the values, similar to the Line 1,2 and 4. And need to parse, for example in the first line, `"/home/ukrishnan/projects/test.yml","LOG_DRIVER","syslog"` for all the lines with similar format. Please help as I'm completely a newbie to `grep` or `awk`.

Edit:
Sorry, if this is two broad. Here is what I tried.

By using, `grep -v "{\|}"` returns,

```
["/home/ukrishnan/projects/test.yml","LOG_DRIVER"]  "syslog"
["/home/ukrishnan/projects/test.yml","IMAGE"]   "mysql:5.6"
["/home/ukrishnan/projects/mysql/app.xml","ENV_ACCOUNT_BRIDGE_ENDPOINT"]    "/u01/src/test/sample.txt"
```

If someone helps me with also grabbing values within double quotes in a single grep, that would be great.

Comment: This is quite broad. What is the underlying logic? What did you try?

Comment: @fedorqui Please check the edit.

Comment: What does `need to parse, for example in the first line, "/home/ukrishnan/projects/test.yml","LOG_DRIVER","syslog" for all the lines with similar format.` mean? You need to at the very least precisely define `similar`. Also, edit your question to show **exactly** the desired output given your posted sample input file.

Answer (score 2):

this one-liner works for your example:

```
awk '$NF~/^[^{]/&&sub(/^\[/,"")+sub(/\]\s*/,",")' file
```

It gives:

```
"/home/ukrishnan/projects/test.yml","LOG_DRIVER","syslog"
"/home/ukrishnan/projects/test.yml","IMAGE","mysql:5.6"
"/home/ukrishnan/projects/mysql/app.xml","ENV_ACCOUNT_BRIDGE_ENDPOINT","/u01/src/test/sample.txt"
```

Comment: Hi Kent, thanks for you answer. Your answer almost works. But there is a tab space coming before last string, for eg., "syslog". Any idea to remove that? Also it would be better without double quotes ;)

Comment: @Mr.Stranger I cannot see the `Tab` in output... I used `\s*`, it will match the tab too. regarding removing the quotes, you can add another `sub()` in the awk one-liner.

Comment: `+gsub(/"/,"")+gsub("\t","")` - Didn't get anyway to remove " and tab space with sub, so I solved it with gsub as above. Any idea to combine these both?

Comment: You're currently thrashing trying to put bandaids on a partial solution instead of taking a step back and really thinking about a clean solution. See the comment I left under your question for the missing info we need to help you.